# Retrieving data from child AppDomain without referencing assemblies from parent domain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I'm trying to develop tool for administering my applications. Tool needs to know certain informations from concrete app. I would like to retrieve that data without referencing all assemblies referenced by those applications.
This is code I have:

**MetadataLoader.dll:**

```cs
public class MetadataLoader 
{
    public MetadataLoader(MetadataSource source) 
    {
        ...
    }

    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class MetadataSource 
{
    public void Load(string path) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Metadata.dll:**

```cs
public class Metadata 
{
    ...
}
```

**Tool.dll:**

```cs
public class Worker 
{
    public void Execute() 
    {
        // create new domain
        // create metadataloader instance
        //  - create metadatasource instance and call Load. Path should be passed from this method. 
        //  - create MetadataLoader instance 
        //  - fetch MetadataLoader.Metadata
        // >>> Tool.dll should reference only Metadata.dll, not MetadataLoader.dll
    }
}
```

Also, I can't change MetadataSource class since it's in third party library (this is simplified example). 
How can I implement Execute method?

**UPDATE:** 
MetadataLoader.dll and Tool.dll reference different versions of same assembly (third party library mentioned in initial question) so Tool.dll mustn't reference version used by MetadataLoader.dll.

Tool.dll references: 
- ThirdParty.v2.dll
- Metadata.dll

MetadataLoader.dll references:
- ThirdParty.v1.dll
- Metadata.dll

To give this problem more context. Both Tool.dll and MetadataLoader.dll use same ORM to access database. ORM also provides object model metadata. Tool.dll uses ORM to access its own database, but also needs to access object models of administered applications. Tool.dll mustn't depend on ORM version administered applications use. That is why I want to load administered application into its own "container" (AppDomain).

Comment: But you can change `Metadata` and `MetadataLoader` classes, right?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer to wrap them instead of changing them (if that's possible).

Comment: What kind of metadata are you returning?

Comment: @dmck My custom metadata consisting of plain C# objects.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should create a new assembly with shared code. In particular, you should create a wrapper for MetadataSource. It is necessary only because the `MetadataSource` class is defined in a third-party library and you can't change it directly to inherit from [`MarshalByRefObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).

```
public class MetadataSourceWrapper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public MetadataSource MetadataSource { get; private set; }

    public MetadataSourceWrapper()
    {
        MetadataSource = new MetadataSource();
    }

    public void Load(string path)
    {
        MetadataSource.Load(path);
    }
}
```

Note, that it should inherit from `MarshalByRefObject` to allow you to access the instances of this class from different AppDomains.

You should also define `IMetadataLoader` interface as follows:

```
public interface IMetadataLoader
{
    void Init(MetadataSourceWrapper source);
    Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

After that, change the `MetadataLoader` class to inherit from `MarshalByRefObject` and to implement `IMetadataLoader` as follows:

```
public class MetadataLoader : MarshalByRefObject, IMetadataLoader
{
    public MetadataLoader() { }

    public void Init(MetadataSourceWrapper source)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

And finally implement the `GetMetadata` method:

```
public static Metadata GetMetadata(
    string metadataLoaderApplicationBase, /*e.g. `C:\MyCompany\MyApp*`*/
    string metadataLoaderAssemblyName, /*e.g. `MetadataLoader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` or `MetadataLoader`*/
    string sharedDllAssemblyName, /*e.g. `Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` or `Shared`*/
    string metadataSourcePath
)
{
    AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
    domainSetup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyName);

    Evidence evidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;

    AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AppDomain Friendly Name",
        evidence, domainSetup);

    MetadataSourceWrapper msw =
        (MetadataSourceWrapper)newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(sharedDllAssemblyName,
            "YourNamespace.MetadataSourceWrapper" /*full type name including the namespace*/);
    msw.Load(metadataSourcePath);

    IMetadataLoader metadataLoader =
        (IMetadataLoader)newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(metadataLoaderAssemblyName,
            "YourNamespace.MetadataLoader" /*full type name including the namespace*/);
    metadataLoader.Init(msw);

    Metadata metadata = metadataLoader.Metadata;
    AppDomain.Unload(newDomain);
    return metadata;
}
```

In regards to references:

- Shared.dll will reference only the third-party DLL that contains `MetadataSource`.
- MetadataLoader.dll and Tool.dll will reference third-party DLL and the Shared.dll.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your effort and detailed explanation. However, your solution doesn't work for me. I think my question wasn't detailed enough so I updated it with additional information.

Comment: Nikolay, I decided to create new app that will provide my app with data. I will use WCF for inter app communication. It seems easier and cleaner to use WCF instead of AppDomain approach. Thank you for your help.